# Compiler error in mingw-w64: 'undefined reference to `__getreent.'

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, libjpeg

I'm currently in the (nightmare) task of trying to compile cImg and libjpeg in Windows. After many hours, I was finally able to build libjpeg and I've included it within the build process (cImg needs libjpeg to work with jpegs).

When I try to compile with 'g++ image.cpp libjpeg.a -lgdi32' I get the following error:

```
'jerror.c:112: undefined reference to `__getreent. The system cannot find the path specified.'
```

I've had a look on google but there doesn't seem to be many people with the same issue (and fewer still with answers).

I'm compiling in windows using mingw-w64.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved this. For anyone who has the same problem:

- Make sure that you are compiling libjpeg.a and cImg with the same compiler (i.e. gcc or mingw-w64)
- Due to difficulties compiling libjpeg with mingw-w64 i used the gcc compiler but if you are using this library you need to compile cImg with gcc as well (which causes other issues...)
- I eventually managed to compile libjpeg with mingw-w64 in MSYS2 by changing the Path. To do this you need to inherit the Windows Path  - edit 'msys2_shell.cmd' and remove `'rem'` from `'set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit'`